# how to place log files out side of jetty home..?

Tags: logging, jetty, jetty-9

I have place log4j properties in resourced directory and jetty is now writing logs in files in **${jetty.home}/logs/ directory** with some auto generated name like this **2014_02_11.stderrout.log.071800746** but In my log4j properties I specified like below,

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=**/var/log/search-service/jetty.log**

log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1`enter code here`
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.append=true
```

is this possible to write jetty server logs outside of jetty home,if yes how to do that.someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to Jetty's own logs, not your webapp's logs: you can override the base log directory with the `jetty.logs` system property.

Depending on how you start Jetty, it may be as simple as adding the property to your command line. For example:

```
java -jar -Djetty.logs=/var/log/search-service/jetty.system.log start.jar
```